# Unknown extension after upgrading CiviCRM in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

Updrading from CiviCRM 4.6.4 to latest (4.7) and using wordpress 4.4.5..

The upgrade process showed no errors, in fact it showed "Done" and began to redirect to a url that never loaded. I clicked on "Civicrm" on the left sidebar of wordpress and nothing. I went to the base url of the wp install and this message appears:

`Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
Unknown extension: nz.co.fuzion.payflowlink
Return to home page.`

Found this in /wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog

`Dec 16 10:59:28  [info] 
$Fatal Error Details = array(3) {
  ["message"]=>
  string(43) "Unknown extension: nz.co.fuzion.payflowlink"
  ["code"]=>
  NULL
  ["exception"]=>
  object(CRM_Extension_Exception_MissingException)#978 (10) {
    ["errorData":"CRM_Core_Exception":private]=>
    array(1) {
      ["error_code"]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["cause":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_trace":"PEAR_Exception":private]=>
    NULL
    ["message":protected]=>
    string(43) "Unknown extension: nz.co.fuzion.payflowlink"
    ["string":"Exception":private]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["code":protected]=>
    int(0)
    ["file":protected]=>
    string(104) "/Users/me/Sites/donate_new/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Container/Collection.php"
    ["line":protected]=>
    int(150)
    ["trace":"Exception":private]=>
    array(30) {
      [0]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(104) "/Users/me/Sites/donate_new/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Container/Collection.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(111)
        ["function"]=>
        string(12) "getContainer"
        ["class"]=>
        string(34) "CRM_Extension_Container_Collection"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "->"
        ["args"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(24) "nz.co.fuzion.payflowlink"
        }
      }`

Comment: Is PayFlow a wordpress extension or a CiviCRM extension? CMS CiviCRM extensions need to be turned off before upgrading.

Comment: @Christia That's good to know! I was following a civi guide that makes no mention of extensions: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installing+CiviCRM+for+WordPress
I will try doing an upgrade again but with extensions turned off.

Comment: @Christia After turning off the extensions and deleting that extension, the upgrade went through normally. That's not to say I have new issues lol. Thanks!

Comment: Great! I posted this as an answer so others can benefit also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off contributed CiviCRM extensions, (such as PayFlow) before upgrading. Then turn them back on or reinstall them.

From the guide, "Because of the huge number and ever-changing nature of community contributed Wordpress plugins, CiviCRM cannot guarantee compatibility with contributed plugins. A list of know incompatibilities can be found at WordPress plugins/themes incompatible with CiviCRM." 
Check the compatibility list.

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installing+CiviCRM+for+WordPress